# Remote Debugging Web App without USB

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently using USB connection to debug my web application using chrome's inspect devices. During demonstration or presentation, I would not be connecting my mobile device to my PC client but I would want to see the console logs on my PC just in case there are any abnormal events happening. Is there anyway to do it via WIFI?

Or do I have to send my output data over to my web-service and to see it from there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it via wifi.

1) Connect your device to pc using adb.
2) Enable developer option.
3) Open terminal/console.
4) Run following command
   1) adb tcpip 7777
   2) adb connect 192.168.1.77:7777

Replace 192.168.1.77 with your android device ip.

5) Once it will successfully connected you can remove cable and perform your demonstration. you will get console logs via wifi.

Answer (score 4):

**You can! Follow these steps:**

1. Connect device via USB and make sure debugging is working.

   (GO To the root directory of your sdk)

> For my case it's > C:\Users\johnrao\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Shift Right Click and open command  here (Windows)

2. adb connect "your device ip address"

That works for me!

Comment: Only after adding tcpip , it works for me but thank you anyway!